# Is there a Canadian equivalent to Mobile Passport?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, canada, canadian-citizens

I just learned about this [app](http://mobilepassport.us/) that lets US citizens fill their customs form and submit it from their phones. I looked on [CBSA's website](http://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/new-neuf/app-eng.html) but couldn't find anything similar.

Is there a way for frequent (and impatient) travelers to Canada to submit their customs forms faster than with the current paper form ?

Answer (score 2):

## Nexus

From the [Canadian Border Services Agency](http://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/prog/nexus/menu-eng.html):

> NEXUS is designed to speed up border crossings for low-risk, pre-approved travellers into Canada and the United States (U.S.). It is jointly run by the Canada Border Services Agency and U.S. Customs and Border Protection.

To apply, you can visit [the official webiste](http://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/prog/nexus/goes-eng.html).

Comment: You can also check out http://www.fasttrackpassportcontrol.com/nexus-faqs for application.

Comment: It sure makes immigration easier but I can't find anywhere that Nexus does away with the customs paper declaration or speeds it up

Comment: Just go to any border crossing that has Nexus, you will see that the Nexus lines go way, way faster.  I'll glance around for an internet source if I have a chance.

Comment: @blackbird, check out http://www.theglobeandmail.com/globe-drive/culture/commuting/life-in-the-fast-lane-should-i-get-a-nexus-card/article16090274/

Comment: @blackbird, I know this is just one guys blog, but there's http://www.arielbravy.com/travel/2014/03/24/how-to-speed-up-border-crossings-nexus-pass-tsa-precheck-global-entry/ too.

Comment: Quote: `Faster border inspection time. Customs and Border Patrol estimate that it takes NEXUS card holders 10 seconds at the border guard’s inspection booth.`  A bit faster, lol.  That's from http://canada.immigrationvisaforms.com/canada-travel-program-forms/nexus-pass.

Comment: @blackbird, for more, just search Google for `Does nexus speed up the border`, it should give you something.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, nexus lines go fast. The nexus card does make a big difference. The idea that it’s comparable to the mobile passport is pretty humerous though.  Nexus applications must be downloaded and printed, filled out, then faxed; plus, It costs $138.    The mobile passport took a minute to download, another to upload the passport, another to add travel
Info and it was entirely free. Pretty amazing speed up as we travelled in!